# How to AES ECB mode encrypt using cryptocipher?

Tags: haskell, encryption, aes

I'd like to use http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptocipher-0.6.1/docs/Crypto-Cipher.html to encrypt a ByteString. Here's my sorry attempt:

```
import Crypto.Cipher
import Crypto.Cipher.AES (AES128)
import Crypto.Cipher.Types
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

key = B.pack "It a 128-bit key"

main = do 
     let ctext = ecbEncrypt key (B.pack "16 bytte ssecret") 
     print (B.unpack ctext)
```

It looks like I need to use [`makeKey`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-cipher-types-0.0.4/docs/Crypto-Cipher-Types.html#t%3aKey) and [`cipherInit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-cipher-types-0.0.4/docs/Crypto-Cipher-Types.html#t%3aCipher) in some clever manner, but as a Haskell beginner, I'm struggling to figure out how to use `makeKey`.

I'd deeply appreciate a short sample block or a point to the right direction.

Comment: FYI ECB is very insecure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the type of `ecbEncrypt`.
It takes a `cipher` (`AES128` in your case) and a `ByteString`. `cipher` can be produced by `cipherInit`, which requires a `Key cipher`. `Key`s are made with `makeKey`, which takes an instance of `ToSecureMem` (a `ByteString` will do) and returns an `Either KeyError (Key cipher)`. Ignoring errors, you can simply pattern-match on the `Right` constructor of `Either` to get the key. The code sample looks as follows:

```
import Crypto.Cipher
import Crypto.Cipher.Types
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

keyString = B.pack "It a 128-bit key"

Right key = makeKey keyString

aes128 :: AES128
aes128 = cipherInit key

ptext = B.pack "16 bytte ssecret"

ctext = ecbEncrypt aes128 ptext

main = putStrLn $ B.unpack ctext
```

I've specified the type of `aes128` here directly since the compiler can't know by itself which cipher you are using.